# Retrofit 2, Rx 2 and async calls

Tags: kotlin, retrofit, rx-java2

I'm just beginning with Retrofit and Rx and created a smile API, whith such (Kodein) configuration:

```
bind<CallAdapter.Factory>() with singleton {
    RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create()
}

bind<RetrofitInterface>() with singleton {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .client(instance())
            .baseUrl(instance<String>("apiRoot"))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(instance())
            .addConverterFactory(instance())
            .build()

    retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface::class.java)
}
```

Now it seems that when I call my API methods created by Retrofit, they get subscribed on current thread rather than the thread set in `.subscribeOn(someThread)`, like when I call:

```
    registrationSession(mUserName, PublicKeyType.XXXX, TargetType.YYYY)
            .subscribeOn(io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers.newThread())
            ...
            .subscribe(
                    {

                    },
                    { error ->
                        Log.e("Error", error.message)
                    }
            )
```

the retrofit supplied `registrationSession` will call the request IMMEDIATELY, on main thread, NOT when I subscribe, which I wouldn't expect (but then again - I'm just starting with Rx, I might be wrong)

Just in case you're wondering how registrationSession is definded, it's a simple function wrapper over this:

```
@POST("registration/session")
fun registrationSession(
        @Header(Constants.LB_DEVICEID_HEADER) deviceUuid: String,
        @Body registrationSessionPost: RegistrationSessionPost
): Observable<Response>
```

So what can I do to make `registrationSession` run on different thread? Is there a way?

Comment: I not sure what you mean with "INMEDIATELY, not when I subscribe". You call subscribe right after your method returns the observable. What makes your think that the code won't execute inmediately?

Comment: I thought registrationSession() call would return an observable that will execute underlying remote call on Schedulers.newThread() when subscribed, even though I subscribe immediately like above. If the assumption is wrong - what do I have to do to make it do the request on different thread?

Comment: Yes, it runs with the Scheduler provided in `subscribeOn` method. Are you really sure it runs on main thread?? In theory if you remove the `subscribeOn` line it will run in main thread and produce a "NetworkOnMainThread" exception in your error log if you do network connections there

Comment: I'm sure, because... It gives me "NetworkOnMainThread" the way it is now!

Comment: lol ok, Have you tried the io Scheduler `Schedulers.io()` already? I don't see anything evil in the posted code, I suspect the problem must happen elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

The only reason this may happen is that `subscribeOn` (as opposite to `observeOn`) can be called only once. To be specific first `subscribeOn` call will work, other calls (or operators usages on this stream) will be ignored. Make sure `subscribeOn` it's not called anywhere else on this stream.

Comment: I know that. There's only one subscribeOn call.

Comment: Multiple `subscribeOn` will not be ignored https://akarnokd.blogspot.com/2017/11/when-multiple-subscribeons-do-have.html